# What can we do to settext from this code?

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have a class and I want to have texts from this class to the mainActivity on a textview . Can some one help me ? And I want to call it on text view on main , I tried this but it didn't work

```
private String title;
    private String   test1;
    private String Time;
    private String test2;
    private String report;

    enter code here
    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }    
    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }
    public String getScore() {
        return test2;
    }
    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.test2 = score;
    }
    public String getReport() {
        return report;
    }
    public void setReport(String report) {
        this.report = report;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title; }
```

Comment: and what have you tried? add here code of your Activity class.

Comment: See this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void settextManually(int resourceId,String textsethere)
    View view = findViewById(resourceId);
    if (view instanceof TextView) {
        TextView text = (TextView) view;
            text .setText(textsethere));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the public methods of your string class to set text into your `TextView`. For example:

```
textViewScore.setText(yourClass.getScore());
```

Answer (score 0):

in your mainActivity do this:

```
textViewTime.setText(yourClass.getTime());
textViewScore.setText(yourClass.getScore());
textViewReport.setText(yourClass.getReport());
textViewTitle.setText(yourClass.getTitle());
```